# Node.js/NestJS: force a HTTP call to go (making it a hotter Observable)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, httpservice

I'm developping a library for some end-users, with calls to an API via HttpService whose result **the end-user will use or not**.

```
        end-user consumer <==> my library <=(HTTP)=> remote API
```

Now HttpService uses *cold Observables*, meaning that it will trigger the HTTP call *only* if we subscribe to the generated Observable. If I return this Observable to my end-user, and they don't subscribe to it because in their particular usecase they don't need the result, the API will never be called.

For that reason, I tend to subscribe myself to the Observable before returning it to the end-user, but I'm not exactly sure it's an elegant or safe solution, hence this post. My code looks like this (simplified for the post, and using HttpService from @nestjs/common):

**ServiceToAccessAPIData.ts**

```
export class ServiceToAccessAPIData {
  ...
  callToEndPoint(): Observable<any> {
    const obs = httpService.get(someUrl)
    .pipe(
      shareReplay(1) // see A
    );

    obs.subscribe(()=>{},()=>{}); // see B

    return obs;
  }
  ...
}
```

With:

- **A**: because I want to avoid each subscription to emit an HTTP call, I need to share the call results between subscribers; and because I subscribe now (in B) and the end-user might subscribe later (even after the API sent a result) and they obviously shouldn't miss the result, I use the shareReplay(1) operator, which stores the last result, and emits it to any new subscribers.
- **B**: I subscribe now to force the HTTP call to go immediately. We provide success but *especially error-handling method* because an unhandled Exception blows Node.js server up).

Now, this seems a bit elaborate for such a trivial use-case: *'provide a safe way for the end-user to make a call, whether they use the result or not'*.

**Is there a better, simpler, more elegant way to do so?**

Also, performance-wise, would there be any outcome with this technique?

HttpService Observers emits only once and then completes, so the subscriptions will be automatically 'unsubscribed'. But I'm wondering what becomes of the underlying Observer observed by shareReplay. I suppose it will be garbage-collected when the Observable I return will have no reference on it anymore, but I'm wondering.

---

**Using Promises** (as suggested by MoazzamArif)

The questions above quite remains (especially if needing to stick with Observables), but a solution to the initial problem could be to use *.toPromise()* as the returned value to the end-user.

```
return obs.toPromise();
```

*.toPromise()* **subscribes** to the Observable (having it do the HTTP call immediately) and wraps it in a Promise, which will resolve to the last emitted value of the Observable once the Observable completes (in the case of HttpService, as soon as the API returned a result).

=> This actually answers the need *'provide a safe way for the end-user to make a call, whether they use the result or not'*.

**Now let's dig further.** I suppose this is an exotic and strange scenario to consider, but how could we handle such situation:

- an error occurs during the HTTP call
- the end-user chains .then() and .catch(), but only *after* the error occured

=> because *.toPromise()* subscribes to the Observable directly, but no error handler is provided, the error will bubble up and crash the app

=> if we directly chain `.catch(err => anyValue)` to the returned Promise, the error will be caught, but the end-user will receive *anyValue* in *.then()*, and won't be able to handle the original error

=> if we directly chain `.catch(err => { someHandling(); return Promise.reject(err); }` to the returned Promise, because the user has not chained their *.catch()* yet, the new error coming from the new rejected Promise will bubble up and crash the app

Therefore, I suppose there's no solution, and that above scenario is simply impossible to handle (it was possible to handle it with the Observable .shareReplay(1) solution).

Comment: why not convert http observable to promise `.toPromise()`

Comment: Why not just return the Observable and let Nest subscribe to it under the hood?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel: I don't follow. Nest does not intervene after the Observable is produced. Nest is only mentionned here as the provider of HttpService.

Comment: @MoazzamArif: I was about to explore this option, but at random! In what would that be a solution?

Comment: @Bob if you return an observable, Nest will automatically subscribe to the result and return it to the client for you, meaning you can do all of your logic after the HTTP call in RxJS operators, which adds in the ability for things like `retry` and `retryWhen` without having to go through some extra logic.

Comment: @MoazzamArif: using Promises sounds an acceptable way to go and will probably how I'll handle this. Any insight about the apparently impossible scenario I added at the end of the question?